# Why is my Nikon P900 showing hazy, white lines in the viewfinder?

Tags: nikon, lcd

I am getting hazy lines on the shiny areas of the image, only when I am using manual <s>zoom</s> focus on my p900.

It is not present on the picture itself, but shows up on the viewfinder and the screen. Any Clue? Thanks.

I updated firmware from 1.1 to 1.3, still the same.

[image: Hazy lines on shiny areas of the image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Nikon P900's [focus peaking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxVVBEFyFpI) feature, which is an aid for manual focus.

This feature helps show where the camera is focusing by highlighting what it perceives as in-focus sharp edges in white. As you can see from [Nikon's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxVVBEFyFpI), or [this review](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/nikon-p900/nikon-p900-field-test.htm), you turn the wheel on the back to adjust focus, and can press up and down to change the amount of white shown. (Oddly, this feature is not documented [in the manual](http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/221/COOLPIX_P900.html), but I trust the field-test review indicating that this camera does have it — especially because that's exactly what it looks like.)

I'm not sure if there's a setting to turn it off — you may just be able to dial it down all the way when in use. But, I'm also not sure why you'd *want* to — this is one of the easiest and best tools for nailing manual focus with an LCD screen.

Comment: So they give it focus peaking but leave it out of the manual? That's strange.

Comment: @MichaelClark Yes, strange. My first thought was that it might have been added in a firmware update, but the [firmware changelog](http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/166.html) doesn't mention it. No mention on Nikon's [P900 page](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/compact-digital-cameras/coolpix-p900.html), either — but it's confirmed by [other reviews, too](https://photographylife.com/reviews/nikon-coolpix-p900/2/).

Comment: Also [this third-party guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=9pbzCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA162&ots=W_esfQGM8g&dq=p900%20focus%20peaking%20firmware&pg=PA162#v=onepage&q&f=false), which gives the feature a couple of paragraphs (and notes that there's a menu item to disable it).

Comment: Weirdly, it _is_ mentioned in Nikon's [P900 press release](http://www.nikon.com/news/2015/0302_cpx_03.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If it is not in the photos themselves then it is likely a scaling artifact. Your camera has a much higher resolution than the LCD screen on the back of it. The sensor produces 16 megapixel images. The LCD screen and the electronic viewfinder are less than one megapixel each. When the camera scales your 16MP images down to 921K dots it has to squeeze the information from many pixels in the image to only one dot on your screen or viewfinder. The camera is designed to do it quickly and with less processing (to save battery life). This results in the artifacts you are seeing when you review your images. Some of it appears to be straight up aliasing, which is just a fancy name for the stairstep pattern of a diagonal line on a relatively low resolution screen.